# withColumn is not giving expected result with groupby in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
 +----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------------+
|CustomerNo|TransactionDate|SKUItemID|one_day_back_date|last_12month_date_from_trans|
+----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------------+
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297636|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297637|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297638|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297639|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297640|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297642|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297643|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297644|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2020-08-04|  1297645|       2020-08-03|                  2019-08-04|
|   10080.0|     2018-06-26|    33559|       2020-08-03|                  2017-06-26|
|   10080.0|     2018-07-03|    36725|       2020-08-03|                  2017-07-03|
|   10080.0|     2018-07-03|    36726|       2020-08-03|                  2017-07-03|
|   10080.0|     2018-07-03|    36727|       2020-08-03|                  2017-07-03|
|   10080.0|     2018-07-03|    36728|       2020-08-03|                  2017-07-03|
|  216988.0|     2019-12-24|   812294|       2019-12-23|                  2018-12-24|
|  216988.0|     2019-12-24|   812298|       2019-12-23|                  2018-12-24|
+----------+---------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------------+
```

I need to get the total items based on the date condition I am using in the below code

```
c=x.withColumn('total_items',(F.col('TransactionDate')<F.col('one_day_back_date')) & (F.col('TransactionDate') >= F.col('last_12month_date_from_trans'))) \
.groupBy('CustomerNo').agg(F.count('SKUItemID').alias('total_items'))
```

I need to get '5' as total_items for the customer 10080.0 but when I am applying the above code,  I am getting '14' as total_items. I used filter as well but this will not give all the rows when applied on the large datasets

Output that I got

```
+----------+-----------+
|CustomerNo|total_items|
+----------+-----------+
|   10080.0|         14|
+----------+-----------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----------+-----------+
|CustomerNo|total_items|
+----------+-----------+
|   10080.0|         5 
   216988.0          0
+----------+-----------+
```

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new column, `total_items`, but you are not using that for anything. I think you should apply a filter instead. Somthing like

```
c=x.where((F.col('TransactionDate')<F.col('one_day_back_date')) & (F.col('TransactionDate') >= F.col('last_12month_date_from_trans'))) \
.groupBy('CustomerNo').agg(F.count('SKUItemID').alias('total_items'))
```

That will take the rows where you criteria is met, and then count the number of records in each group.

To also get the zero count, you can do something like:

```
c=(x.withColumn('toCount', 
                F.when( (F.col('TransactionDate')<F.col('one_day_back_date')) 
                       & 
                        (F.col('TransactionDate') >= F.col('last_12month_date_from_trans'))
                       , 1)
                .otherwise(0) 
               )
   .groupBy('CustomerNo')
   .agg(F.sum('toCount').alias('total_items')))
```

It will mark the items to count with a `1` in column `toCount` and sum the `toCount` column pr. group.

Comment: It is giving the correct result. I applied the same logic on the larger dataset where I have other customer records as well. I am not getting the other customer rows when I applied your logic. I have a total of 500k rows but I am getting only 200k. Some customers are missing

Comment: That's great. What do you get if you remove the `filter`/`where` part of the query? Maybe the filter is removing the other `CustomerNo`s?

Comment: I think so. I updated the table. The customers with customerNo 216988 are missing. I need to get 0 if the criteria doesn't match

Comment: I have updated my answer to also give the zero count